# Am I understanding this block of code correctly?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a cordova sqlite plugin. My question does not require you to have an understanding of the API. I'm not having any issues. I'm just a little uncertain about my understanding of the code below and how it works. I'm trying to have a much better understanding of the code I write.

1. So first, this variable "db" is defined as being a function (object) named "openDatabase" with parameters that the plugin understands and it's being called.
2. "db" which is actually a function (object) called "openDatabase" has a method called "transaction".

Am I doing alright so far?

Here's where I get a little confused: The db variable which is now equivalent to the openDatabase function has a method called transaction and it has a self invoking function as a parameter and the self invoking function has this variable "tx" as a parameter? Where does "tx" come from? Is it an object the "openDatabase" function returns after it's called? or is it not returned from "openDatabase" and it's just simply an object from the plugin? Is it always safe to assume variables as parameters that I haven't defined anywhere, that work, have been defined in the plugin, library or API I'm using? My last question is, why use a self invoking function as a parameter instead of a variable defined as that self invoking function? Any benefit? Thank you.

```
var db = openDatabase("DBTest", "1.0", "Sample Description", 200000);

db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Table1Test", [], function(tx, result) {
    for (var i = 0, item = null; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
        item = result.rows.item(i);
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML +=
            '<li><span> + item['text'] + '</span></li>';
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you guessing? Why don't you read cordova documentation. I think it is pretty good and clear. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what's happening in that code, then I get to your specific questions:

`db` is being set to the *return value* from `openDatabase`. Then, the code calls `db.transaction`, passing in a callback function. The callback is called by `db.transaction`, which supplies the `tx` value, and in the callback we call `tx.executeSql`, passing in a second callback function. `executeSql` calls that second callback with the results, which code inside the second callback loops through.

Your questions:

> So first, this variable "db" is defined as being a function (object) named "openDatabase" with parameters that the plugin understands and it's being called.

No. `openDatabase` is being **called**, and `db` is being set to its return value. That return value appears to be an object, but not a function (although it could be, there's no evidence that it is and it probably isn't).

> "db" which is actually a function (object) called "openDatabase" has a method called "transaction".

Yes, except that `db` is probably not a function (although it could be), it's just an object.

> The db variable which is now equivalent to the openDatabase function...

It isn't.

> ...has a method called `transaction` and it has a self invoking function as a parameter...

It's not self-invoking.

> ...and the self invoking function has this variable "tx" as a parameter? Where does "tx" come from?

Because the callback function *isn't* self-invoking, the `tx` argument's value comes from whoever calls the callback. The code in the `transaction` method will call the anonymous callback in that code. When it does, it will supply the value of the `tx` argument to that function. Similarly, the callback passed into `executeSql` will get called with values for `tx` and `result`.

> Is it always safe to assume variables as parameters that I haven't defined anywhere...

Probably not. Instead, continue your study of JavaScript (you're clearly in the process of learning, which is great). You'll learn the syntax and be able to tell what's an argument, what's a variable, etc. Here's some info on that as comments:

```
var db = openDatabase("DBTest", "1.0", "Sample Description", 200000);
//  ^^---- variable

db.transaction(function(tx) {
// Argument ------------^^
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Table1Test", [], function(tx, result) {
// Arguments ----------------------------------------------^^--^^^^^^
        for (var i = 0, item = null; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
// Variables ----^------^^^^
            item = result.rows.item(i);
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML +=
                '<li><span>' +
                item['text'] + '</span></li>';
        }
    });
});
```

---

Part of the confusion here seems to be with callbacks, so let's look at a much simpler version of callbacks, and one where we can see both sides of it.

Suppose something provides us a function, `countUp`, which we can give a start and end value to, and which will then call us with each value between:

```
countUp(0, 5, function(value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

And suppose when we use that, we get:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

In our code above, we *create* but never *call* the callback we're passing to `countUp`. It's **`countUp`'s code** that calls the callback. Here's what `countUp` might look like:

```
function countUp(start, end, callback) {
//                           ^^^^^^^^---- the callback argument
    var i;
    for (i = start; i < end; ++i) {
//      vvvvvvvv------- calls our callback
        callback(i);
//               ^----- passing in this, which we get as `value`
    }
}
```

**Live Example:**

```js
function countUp(start, end, callback) {
  var i;
  for (i = start; i < end; ++i) {
    callback(i);
  }
}

countUp(0, 5, function(value) {
  snippet.log(value);
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How though, is the function being called if it's not a self invoking function and it has no name? Is it being automatically called since it's a parameter of transaction? and is there a benefit to having a function as a parameter with the entire block of function code, instead of having a variable as a parameter which has been defined as that function?

Comment: @codebmanj: The code you see is not calling those functions. Instead, they (the actual function objects) are being passed into `transaction` and `executeSql` as arguments. Later, code in `transaction`/`executeSql` will call the function they've been given. This is called a "callback." If you've ever used `setTimeout` or an event handler, the functions used there are also callbacks: `setTimeout(function() { /*...*/ }, 3000);` passes the function to the browser's timer mechanism. Later, when the time passes, the browser calls the function. Same sort of thing here.

Comment: @codebmanj: The function `db.transaction()` will call the function you pass to it. Since it's `db.transaction()` that calls the function it is not self-invoking.

Comment: @codebmanj: Since some of the confusion here seems to be around callbacks, I've added a simple discussion of them and a simpler example.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. :)

Answer (score 0):

> So first, this variable "db" is defined as being a function (object) named "openDatabase" with parameters that the plugin understands and it's being called.

No. The function stored in `openDatabase` is **called** and it's **return value** is assigned to `db`.

> "db" which is actually a function (object) called "openDatabase" has a method called "transaction".

The value assigned to `db` is an object.

It *might* be a function, but there's no evidence in the code to suggest that it is.

It does have a method called `transaction`.

> it has a self invoking function as a parameter

No, it doesn't.

```
foo( function () { } );
bar( function () { }() );
```

`foo` has a *function* as an argument.

`bar` has the *return value* of an immediately invoked function expression as an argument.

You can't have an IIFE as an argument itself because the IIFE resolves before the value is passed to the function.

`transaction` has a function passed as an argument.

> Where does "tx" come from?

The `transaction` function (assuming the anonymous function doesn't get passed around some more first) will call the anonymous function. It will pass it arguments when it does.

> Is it always safe to assume variables as parameters that I haven't defined anywhere, that work, have been defined in the plugin, library or API I'm using?

Yes

> My last question is, why use a self invoking function as a parameter instead of a variable defined as that self invoking function?

If you mean *Why use a function expression instead of a function stored in a variable?* then it just saves the step of creating the variable and it keeps all the code together.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful response. I have two more questions if you don't mind. 1. the user "T.J. crowder" above, said in response to my second to last question asking if it's always safe to assume variables as parameters I haven't defined anywhere that work, have been defined in the plugin, library, or API, "Probably not. Instead, continue your study of JavaScript (you're clearly in the process of learning, which is great)."

So I'm confused.

Also, how can I be sure "openDatabase" is returning an object to my variable "db" instead of being an object itself with methods?

Comment: If experimental evidence says it is correct, then it is probably correct. As for what `openDatabase` returns (a) You can see it and (b) You can read the manual

Answer (score 0):

`openDatabase` is a funtion which returns an object that gets assigned to the `db` variable. This object has a method, `transaction`, which takes a function as an argument. When you call the transaction method, it sets up a transaction and then calls the function you pass it, with the newly-created transaction as its argument (the `tx` in your example). The function can now use the transaction to query the database. When it returns, the `transaction` method will do any necessary cleanup, and then return to the toplevel code.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment yet doesn't directly answer the question. However, understanding this concept will hopefully allow you to answer all your questions yourself. Therefore I'm posting this as an answer.

### Main concept: Functions are just objects just like numbers, strings etc.

You've probably seen code that looks like this:

```
var x = function (a) {...}
```

That is not a special syntax to declare functions. It is merely possible because functions are first class in javascript. First-class refers to things in the programming language that can be treated as data. In most languages numbers and arrays are first-class "things" (I'll avoid using the word "object" for now because it may have specific meanings in some languages, javascript included). In a lot of languages strings are also first-class things. In a few languages even functions are first class things.

Javascript is one language where functions are first-class: they can be treated as data

```
function x () {};

// you can assign them to variables:
var y = x;
y(); // call the function

// you can put them in arrays:
var a = [x,y];
a[0](); // call the function

// you can pass them as argument:
funtion b (foo) {
    foo(); // call the function passed to b()
}
b(x); // this will cause b() to call x()
```

So when you see this:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {/*...*/});
```

it's basically doing this:

```
function my_function (tx) {/*...*/}

db.transaction(my_function);
```

Therefore, you can sort of guess that `db.transaction()` looks something like this:

```
db.transaction = function (another_function) {
    /* complicated processing ... */

    another_function(result); // pass result variable to the function
                              // the user gave us.
}
```

So when you call:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {/*...*/});
```

the function `db.transaction()` will call your function and pass it an argument (which you have defined as `tx`).

Think of `tx` as sort of the *return* value from `db.transaction()`.